# Automatically formatting punctuation using biblatex field format

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

Customising a [biblatex](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) style, I’d like to use ‘traditional’ typography where the format of punctuation follows that of the preceding text, for example

> *J. Organomet. Chem.* **691.** 13

with the full stop after ‘691’ in bold. I'm pretty sure that `biblatex` can do this automatically, but cannot find how to achieve it. From the documentation, `\setpunctfont` seems to be the function I want, but something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}\setpunctfont{\textbf}}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

fails (my example text is in ref. 3 in the resulting output). I’d rather not have to code the formatting in by hand, as it make maintenance awkward: how is this supposed to be done?

Comment: From reading the documentation it appears that `\mkbibbold` should do that automatically. Perhaps this is a bug?

Comment: @Alan: No, a bug in my reading of the manual :-)

Comment: Except that I don't think it actually works. Removing the `\setpunctfont{\textbf}` doesn't change anything in your example, yet `\mkbibbold` should make the punctuation following the volume number bold.

Comment: Now reading your answer, you weren't the only one who had a bug in reading the manual. :-)

Comment: @Alan: I've updated the answer to use a comma: try with and without `punctfont` to see the effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Re-reading the manual, I find what I'm after is the `punctfont` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,punctfont]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```